# My project with Entity Framework does not get the current information from the database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework in my project and at a point in the flow project, it calls the second system to process and to update some information in the database.

But when the second system finish, my project tries to get this information again from the database, but it returns the old information.

I'm using .NET 7.0 with Entity Framework 6 and SqLite 3.0.

This is part of my code:

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
using var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Totem.App.appsettings.json");

var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .AddJsonStream(stream)
                    .Build();
builder.Configuration.AddConfiguration(config);

var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<AppDbContext>()
                        .UseSqlite(DesignTimeDbContextFactory.GetConnectionString(config))
                        .Options;

var factory = new PooledDbContextFactory<AppDbContext>(options);
var context = factory.CreateDbContext();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(DesignTimeDbContextFactory.GetConnectionString(config)));

builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IBaseRepository<>), typeof(BaseRepository<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryService, CategoryService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductService, ProductService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBannerService, BannerService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthorService, AuthorService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IConfigService, ConfigService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMeasureService, MeasureService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICartService, CartService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IItemCartService, ItemCartService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBranchService, BranchService>();
```

And here's my `BaseRepository`:

```
public class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable, IBaseRepository<TEntity> where TEntity :  class
{
        protected readonly AppDbContext _context;

        #region constructors
        public BaseRepository(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        #endregion

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _context.Dispose();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(true);
        }

        public virtual void Insert(TEntity obj)
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Add(obj);
        }

        public virtual void Update(TEntity obj)
        {
            _context.Entry(obj).State = Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual void Delete(int id)
        {
            _context.Set<TEntity>().Remove(GetById(id));
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>();
        }

        public virtual TEntity GetById(int id)
        {
            return _context.Set<TEntity>().Find(id);
        }

        public virtual void SaveChanges()
        {
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
}
```

I tried to use `AddTransient` and `AddSingleton`, but this not solved.

Comment: Show the place where you call the other system and read back the updated infromation - which fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will almost certainly be a case where the `DbContext` in the first case that is repeat-reading is scoped across the operation of the second process updating the data, so when you fetch the record again you are just getting what is in the tracking cache.

I don't know what the significance of this line:

```
var context = factory.CreateDbContext();
```

That may be just to check that you can instantiate a `DbContext`, but if that reference is injected anywhere it would be treated as a Singleton which wouldn't be good.

The next thing I would strongly recommend is get rid of the `BaseRepository`. This is a generic repository pattern, which is an anti-pattern for `EF`. Looking at the code it is an anemic facade over the `DbContext`. Just use the `DbContext`. When dealing with lifetime scoped injected `DbContexts` you also do not want your code disposing of references provided by the container, that is the container's job unless you have defined the reference to be transient and externally owned. Changing the `DbContext` registration to Transient won't help if the scope of the services/repositories are longer lived. When the container constructs those services it will resolve a `DbContext`, the Transient would just ensure they are each given their own instance of a `DbContext`, but that instance lives as long as the referencing class.

To the meat of the issue: EF's tracking cache. This is used by default so that `EF` can track changes made to entities and ensure that multiple requests for the same entity receive the same instance.  This is great when working with update scenarios, but works against you when reading data that you expect may be modified in the background by another process.  For read operations where you want to ensure you are getting the latest data, and since you aren't editing that data, you don't need to track any changes, use `AsNoTracking()` in the query:

For instance, to read the current data state of ItemCarts:

```
var carts = await ItemCarts
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Where(x => /* criteria */)
    .ToListAsync();
```

This query will always pull the data state from the DB. The entities retrieved will not be put in the tracking cache (making it a bit faster) and it will not read any entities that might happen to be in the tracking cache either.

Answer (score 0):

If You want the changes to the database made from the second system, to be visibles from the first context also, after saved and disposed the second system, You must write (returning in the first outermost context scope):

```
_context.ChangeTracker.Clear();
```

After that, ALL CHANGES will be visibles to the first one also. You can use also, in the first context queries, the **.AsNoTracking()** method, so the data will be taken from the database (not from the changetracker cache).

P.S. If You like, the right syntax for the Dispose method is:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    _context.Dispose();
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```